# Dataframe to custom XML

Tags: xml, r

I have a dataframe as

```
         Sales       PctSales
Id1     12929.63      0.12278547
Id2     90063.39      0.85528156
Id3      2309.60      0.02193298
```

I want to save this data in SQL Server. I am using RODBC. So, I need to convert it to XML. Which might look like this.

```
<salesReport>
    <employee id="Id1" sales="12929.63" pctSales="0.12278547"/>
    <employee id="Id2" sales="90063.39" pctSales="0.85528156"/>
    <employee id="Id3" sales="2309.60" pctSales="0.02193298"/>
</salesReport>
```

First column in input data does not have column name.

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to `XML`? `sqlSave` or `sqlUpdate` works for me just fine for a data.frame...

Comment: I am using a Stored Proc at database end and this SP performs other things as well based on this dataset.

Comment: I am able to get somewhat similar results but first column as it has not colname creating problem any suggestion?

Comment: It is strange, because `sqlSave` has `rownames = TRUE` by default. Though you could just convert your rownames to a column in R and then use `sqlSave`. Assuming your data set is called `df`, you could simply do `df$id <- row.names(df)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of methods in the `XML` package to construct XML:

```
library(XML)
myData <- read.table(text = "Sales       PctSales
Id1     12929.63      0.12278547
Id2     90063.39      0.85528156
Id3      2309.60      0.02193298", header = TRUE, row.names = 1
                     , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
myData$id <- rownames(myData)
names(myData) <- c("id", "sales", "pctSales")

con <- xmlOutputDOM("salesReport")
for(i in seq(nrow(myData))){
  con$addTag("employee", attrs = myData[i,])
}

> con$value()
<salesReport>
  <employee sales="12929.63" pctSales="0.12278547" id="Id1"/>
  <employee sales="90063.39" pctSales="0.85528156" id="Id2"/>
  <employee sales="2309.6" pctSales="0.02193298" id="Id3"/>
</salesReport>
```

I find constructing `XML` using the `XML` package can be slow however and for simple cases I just use a template and something like the `whisker` package.

To export the `XML`as a string use `saveXML`:

```
> cat(saveXML(con$value()))
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<salesReport>
 <employee id="12929.63" sales="0.12278547" pctSales="Id1"/>
 <employee id="90063.39" sales="0.85528156" pctSales="Id2"/>
 <employee id="2309.6" sales="0.02193298" pctSales="Id3"/>
</salesReport>
```